# go install in dockerfile takes a lot of time

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using [`go-jet`](https://github.com/go-jet/jet) to generate models from my DB, therefore I need to run `jet` before `go build`. And I need to install it via `go install`, otherwise docker cant find the `jet` executable. I'v encountered a problem:
when I rebuild my app, docker redownloads go-jet every time (it takes 60-80 seconds).

Is there a better way to generate (or to cache jet library)? It is taking way too long to install

I'v tried to cache `jet` inside Dockerfile, but it gets redownloaded again:

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/go/pkg/mod/ \
    go install github.com/go-jet/jet/v2/cmd/jet@latest
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN go install github.com/go-jet/jet/v2/cmd/jet@latest

CMD sh deployments/startup.sh
```

My startup.sh:

```
jet -dsn="postgresql://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${POSTGRES_HOST}:${POSTGRES_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DB}?sslmode=disable" -schema=public -path=.gen
cd cmd/app
go build
./app
```

And my docker-compose just in case:

```
version: '3.9'

x-common-variables: &database-credentials
  POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
  POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
  POSTGRES_HOST: ${POSTGRES_HOST}
  POSTGRES_PORT: ${POSTGRES_PORT}

services:
  cache:
    image: redis:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    command: redis-server
    environment:
      - REDIS_PORT=6379

  database:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: db
    environment:
      <<: *database-credentials
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10

  migrate:
    image: migrate/migrate
    volumes:
      - ../internal/app/storage/postgres/migrations:/migrations
    command: -path /migrations -database "postgresql://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@db:${POSTGRES_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DB}?sslmode=disable" up
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy

  webapi:
    image: webapi
    build: ../
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - migrate
    environment:
      <<: *database-credentials
```

Comment: Can you commit the generated models to source control?  The setup you're showing recompiles the application every time you run it, which is slow and requires a very large image with the entire Go toolchain.  With this setup it's also possible for the container to fail if the database schema isn't what you expect, which introduces a fragile external dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a very simple solution. I needed to place `go install` before `COPY . .`. What happened: when docker detected changes in project, it dropped app cache (line `COPY . .` ) and all following lines (including `go install`).

My final Dockerfile:

```
...

RUN go install github.com/go-jet/jet/v2/cmd/jet@latest

COPY . .

...
```